# Wait for user input

Tags: bash, git, zsh

I'm creating a little function for a process I have often to repeat.

What I would like to do is that if I call the function parameterless, it will show me the branches and allow me to make the process to the branch I entered, and if I call it with a parameter to make the process on such branch directly

```
function 3bra(){
  #If there's no parameter
  if ["$1" -eq ""]; then
    #show me the branches
    git branch
    #wait for input and give the parameter such entered value
    read $1
  fi

  #checkout to the parameter branch
  git checkout "$1"

  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    #if there are no errors, complete the checkout process
    npm i
    npm rebuild node-sass --force
    npm run start
  fi
}
```

My question is how can I give `$1` the input value, and also exit if nothing is given in the input wait part

Comment: I can't see the question here. Does the script you posted work for you?

Comment: No, it doesn't work :( Sorry, will edit it to make clear what my question is

Comment: ... also `["$1" -eq ""]` is a syntax error (needs whitespace around `[` and `]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
branch=""
function 3bra(){
  #If there's no paramether
  if [[ -z "$*" ]]; then
    #show me the branches
    git branch
    #wait for input and give the paramether such entered value
    echo "Which branch?"
    read -t 10 branch || exit
  else
    #Stuff to do if 3bra is called with params...
    branch="$1"
  fi
  #checkout to the paramether branch
  git checkout "$branch"
  if [[ "$?" -eq 0 ]]; then
    #if there are no errors, complete the checkout process
    npm i
    npm rebuild node-sass --force
    npm run start
  fi
}
#Call the function and pass in the parameters.
3bra "$1"
```

The `read -t 10` specifies a timeout of 10 seconds. If no input is provided, the script exits.

Assuming there are other things in this script, otherwise you wouldn't really need the function call. Save the script and execute it, passing in an argument. It will forward the argument to the function, if present.

Also, I'm not familiar with git, so if something git releated is stuck in the wrong place, well my bad.

Comment: Everything Git-related looks fine. You don't need to declare the variable `branch` before you use it, but if you do, it should be local to the function (i.e. use `local branch` inside the function).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would write it (with footnotes):

```
function 3bra(){
  local branch  # (1)

  if [[ $1 ]]; then  # (2)
    branch="$1"
  else
    # Show branches.
    git branch
    # Get branch from user.
    read branch  # (3, 4)
  fi

  # Checkout the given branch.
  if git checkout "$branch"; then  # (5)
    # Complete the checkout process.
    npm i
    npm rebuild node-sass --force
    npm run start
  fi
}
```

1. This declares the variable `branch` local to the function. This is not required, but it's a good habit.
2. This test (`[[ $1 ]]`) will return false if `$1` is unset or null. It's a more succinct way of doing what you were doing.

   - Yours also had a syntax error here - missing whitespace. Should be `[ "$1" -eq "" ]`
3. When `read`ing a variable, you use the variable name (`branch`), not its contents (`$branch`).
4. It's better to use a named variable than a numbered parameter.

   - Though if you do need to assign to the argument array, you can use `set -- arg1 arg2`
5. This tests the return value directly.

Also if you want to be really thorough, throw an error if too many arguments are provided:

```
if [[ $# -gt 1 ]]; then
  echo "${FUNCNAME[0]}: Too many arguments" >&2
  return 1
fi

if [[ $1 ]]; then
...
```